# OAuth strategies for Facebook/Google services in mobile app with Rails background

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, oauth

I'm developing some iOS app with Rails background. I want to allow users authorizing through Facebook or Google. User mush be authorized before he will be able to make comments and estimate posts. It's my first experience of working with OAuth, then, please, check my steps for client-server architecture:

1. The App gets token/user_id from FB or Google
2. With every request (which requires authorization) to the server the
   app must send user_id and token
3. The server checks if the token is valid
4. If all is good the server responds some data; if token is not valid
   the server returns an exception code.

Please, tell me any advice you think is good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean to say your server will verify whether token came through request is valid facebook or twitter token ?

Comment: If you handle errors properly at both app and server side, than there is no problem with the approach you are planning to implement.